# complex Morse function on a four-manifold

Tags: 4-manifolds, complex-manifolds, morse-theory

If we have a complex Morse function on a complex four-manifold, $f: X\to \mathbb{C} $, can we tell from the function how the genus of inverse images $f^{-1}(z)$ (for regular values) may change? under what conditions can we asssure that the genus does not change?

Comment: There are various notions of being Morse for a function $X\to\mathbb C=\mathbb R^2$.  Could you say specifically which you mean?

Comment: I didn't know there many. I meant a non-degenerate complex-analytic function. Can tell me about the other notions?

Comment: kaavek: Then $f$ is a fibration on open and dense subset with constant genus of the fiber on this subset (I am assuming your function is also proper, otherwise, genus is not even defined). Is this what you wanted to know? 

Comment: In this case $f$ is equivalent, at singular points, to the function $f(z_1, \dots, z_n) = z_1^2 + \cdots + z_n^2$ (in your case, $n=4$). This holds at least with respect to smooth coordinates, I don't know if you can assume holomorphic coordinates. In other words, $f$ is a Lefschetz fibration (assuming proper), and the regular fiber doesn't change in topology.

In the case of real manifolds of even real dimension, this is the starting of the topological Lefschetz fibrations (maps which can be expressed in that way at singular points).

Comment: I am thinking about a Morse theory proof that every Stein 4-manifold admits a Lefschetz fibration over $D^2$. So according to the last comment, we need to show that every Stein admits a non-degenerate complex morse function.Is it possible to use the fact that it can be embedded in $C^n$?  

Comment: So, the manifold $M$ is compact with strictly pseudoconvex boundary. The problem in such a proof is that you don't have control on how the boundary is mapped in the disk. So, the standard proof of this result starts from the handlebody description of $M$ (see the Gompf-Stipsicz book), and try to construct first a branched covering of $B^2 \times B^2$, and then project to the first factor to get a Lefschetz fibration (as in Loi and Piergallini paper). Another approach is to construct a Lefschetz fibration directly from that handlebody, following the ideas of Akbulut and Ozbagci.

Comment: Daneile: I tried to find such a function for a few days but I failed. I do not understand your comment that we don't have control on the boundary. Could you please explain more? 

Comment: kaavek: first, you should clarify what you mean exactly (I though that $D^2$ means the closed 2-disk, isn't?) In this case, $M$ has boundary if you want a nice fibration (and of course, to do that you need much control on the boundary beavior of your function). If by $D^2$ you mean an open disk, and the manifold is open, then is probably much simple, just embed $M$ in $\Bbb C^N$ for some large $N$ and take a generic projection onto a complex line (this can be subtle, but should work).